# Why is shutdown so much slower than previous versions?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown

I have made a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 on my netbook with a SSD disk, but it takes so much longer to shut it down in comparisson with 11.04, 10.10 or 10.04 which were ultra fast.

It will take about 5 times longer, which is annoying...

Is there perhaps some process waiting with a huge timeout ? How could I check this ?

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to answer without a full list of packages on your system and possible the console output that normally is hidden by the shutdown screen. However, some bugs have been fixed in the shutdown (I know because I fixed quite a few myself) that make it safer for your data. A lot of services weren't being terminated properly in previous releases, which sometimes resulted in filesystem corruption! 11.04 had a few fixes for this, and 11.10, a few more. I don't think any of the new methods should add more than 10 seconds to the shutdown though.

Perhaps hit 'pgdn' while shutting down to see if anything is being printed to plymouth's log.

Comment: The 'Esc' key should work too. :-)

Comment: I tried this and found out the problem as well. It turned out my computer was waiting a long time for the network manager. The message I got was "nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down. ..." After uninstalling network-manager it was as quick as I was used to. It seems there is some issue with the network manager.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

I renamed the links in /etc/rc0.d and rc6.d:

- S31umountnfs.sh to S05umountnfs.sh
- S35networking to S15networking

Taken from:[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/903825), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67939/why-does-ubuntu-11-10-start-and-shut-down-so-slowly)