# Why does Ubuntu 11.10 start and shut down so slowly?

Tags: 11.10, boot, shutdown

Ubuntu's always been very fast on my computer. I have 3GB RAM, and previous versions booted in under 40s and shut down in under 5s. Most recently, Natty took 40s to boot and only 4s to shut down. However, since installing Oneiric, my boot time has gone up to 50s and my shut down time to over 11s! A slight increase is fine, but this is quite alarming. I wait for applications to properly terminate, so that's not the issue. The only startup applications I have are Jupiter and Caffeine.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope Unity is still part of the overall Ubuntu experience, even if some other things might have been neglected a little during development, which is debatable. With the transition to GNOME 3, I would imagine the whole desktop needed reworking to account for this. And in only 6 months, no less.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the links `/etc/rc0.d/S35networking` and `/etc/rc6.d/S35networking`.

I've reported [a bug in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/903825).

Comment: You're not far, since this script is currently indirectly a stop-condition for network-manager. However, please don't modify or change the order of those, since it can have much more important effects than just speeding up startup/shutdown time. In other words, there is indeed a bug (thanks for reporting it) but that's not the right way to fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, the only version where booting speed was a factor was Ubuntu 10.10. After that the developers focused on other stuff like better integration between apps, Better Unity usage and feel, compatibility with Gnome-Shell for those users that wanted that, Changes in how apps communicated between each other and many other features that we actually take for granted.

Am not a huge fan of Unity myself but I can not deny that 11.10 came with a punch of big nice changes for Unity and how way we use a desktop. Adapting to Unity is not easy but so far I have seen nice results.

Returning to the question at hand, this also happens to me but is not such a big deal if what is between (Actually using Ubuntu) has been enhanced a lot of ways. It would not surprise me if in some of the minor updates that come every so many days, a small fix would improve the speed of boot time and shutdown time.

+1 to your question since I was also wondering the same thing but seeing the progress Ubuntu made in just 6 months makes us think about how good will 12.04 be.

Comment: I just need to add that once Ubuntu has booted, everything is a lot faster; Nautilus, USC, the works, which just confuses me further.

Comment: I just hope that on the Ubuntu 12.04 cycle the developers will be focused on others thinks than Unity because since Unity appear the Ubuntu developers (I mean the one that work for Canonical) seams to be working mostly if not only on Unity and Unity related features. Because what we have now is a system that take longer to boot and where the overall performance is lesser than what it was a year ago (check Phoronix benchmarks, you'll see). The GNOME 3 apps are faster than on GNOME 2 but that's not the work of Ubuntu developpers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience and disappointment after installing Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)
I looked some more into it to find out (in my case) this was caused by the network-manager. While shutting down it seems to time out and end with the message
   "nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down. ..."

I removed the network-manager and configured my ip address by using /etc/network/interfaces and it is now fast again.

Might be you have the same problem ....

Comment: Fast again at what? Boot or shutdown? And how fast is that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience "Waiting for network configuration", I resolved the proble commenting all the lines in /etc/network/interfaces except

```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
```